# Как изменить насыщенность цвета тайлового слоя?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть ли способ задания насыщенности цвета тайлового слоя карты? По примеру MapKit, но для javascript API? (https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/dg/concepts/style.html#style__format)

Мы отображаем полигоны с цветовой заливкой на карте через ObjectManager, при этом хотим уменьшить насыщенность основного слоя.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Встроенных возможностей в JS API Яндекс Карт по стилизации тайлового слоя не предусмотрено. Вам следует смотреть в сторону CSS-фильтров для ground-пейна, как это, например описано в [блоге Карт](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/44357).